# How to add style definitions to inline svg?

Tags: snap.svg

I have an empty inline SVG in a HTML page and use Snap.SVG to fill and manipulate the SVG. I want to use CSS styles for the SVG elements.

How could I add a `style` section to the SVG (inline style sheets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
element.attr({ style: 'fill: green' });
```

As an example ?

Stylesheet example...

```
var frag = Snap.parse('<defs><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[ rect { stroke: #909; stroke-width: 10; fill: blue; } ]]></style>')
s.append( frag )
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/s2oc410g/6/)

Comment: I want to add the styles (inline style sheets) to the svg?

Comment: I've added an inline stylesheet example.